# Setting tableView datasource is causing app to crash

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift5

I am trying to create a table view with custom cells however whenever i Incorporate the datasource in the viewcontroller the app crashes, i know its this thats crashing the app beacuse when i comment out `EventsList.EventsList_Table.datasource = self` the app runs but the custom cells dont show i have also tried inherting from just UITableViewController but this also crashes the app or at least doesnt load and shows a black screen.

**CustomCell.swift**

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {



override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
    
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.backgroundColor = .white
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.15
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 6
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 6

    
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    
    self.frame = self.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 10, bottom: 15, right: 10))
    
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

**EventsListViewController.swift**

```
class EventsListViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var ListView: EventsListView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        ListView = EventsListView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize().width, height: screenSize().height))
        ListView.EventsList_Table.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "EventsCell")
        ListView.EventsList_Table.separatorStyle = UITableViewCell.SeparatorStyle.none
        ListView.EventsList_Table.delegate = self
        ListView.EventsList_Table.dataSource = self
    self.view.addSubview(ListView)
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    
    }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let Cell =  ListView.EventsList_Table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EventsCell", for : indexPath) as! CustomCell
            Cell.selectionStyle = .none
            Cell.layoutSubviews()
        return Cell
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

}
```

This is the code for the view if this is any help at diagnosing the problem

```
class EventsListView: UIView {


var Events_Title: UILabel = {
    var Title = UILabel()
    Title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    Title.textColor = UIColor(red: 70/256, green: 56/256, blue: 83/256, alpha: 1.0)
    Title.textAlignment = .left
    Title.font = UIFont(name: "GTEestiDisplay-Medium", size: 36)
    Title.text = "Events"
    return Title
}()

var EventsList_Table: UITableView = {
    var Table = UITableView()
    Table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    Table.backgroundColor = .white
    return Table
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    self.addSubview(Events_Title)
    
    Events_Title.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    Events_Title.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
    Events_Title.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    
    self.addSubview(EventsList_Table)
    
    EventsList_Table.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    EventsList_Table.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.9).isActive = true
    EventsList_Table.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: Events_Title.bottomAnchor, constant: 25).isActive = true
    
    
    
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

Comment: What is the crash message? Which line does it crash on?  Simply assigning the datasource won't cause a crash.  You have a bug in one of your datasource functions. The exception message and line will help understand what it is.

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you are registering your cell class against the reuse identifier.  This is probably causing your crash.  Also, it will help the readability of your code if you stick with Swift conventions; Type names (classes and structs) should start with a capital letter.  Variables and properties should start with a lowercase letter. Also, use camelCase and don't use underscores, so `eventsListTable` not `EventsList_Table`

Comment: There is no error message in the console the app just doesnt load as in a complete black screen but if i do not assign the datasource the app loads but the table does not hope thats of some help

Comment: Also i am registering the custom cell on the line ```ListView.EventsList_Table.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "EventsCell")```

Comment: Ok. I see it now. Your code is all over the place. Your app isn't crashing. Showing a black screen isn't a crash. If an app crashes then you are bounced back to the springboard and you get an exception message. You probably have a layout issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are causing your app to hang in an infinite loop because you are setting your cell's frame in `layoutSubviews`.  Setting the frame will invalidate the cell's layout and cause `layoutSubviews` to be called again, where you set the frame and so on.

Commenting the line

```
self.frame = self.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 10, bottom: 15, right: 10))
```

prevents the infinite loop.

I strongly suggest that you adopt auto layout through constraints consistently throughout your app.

When using constraints you should use the `leading` and `trailing` anchors rather than `left` and `right` as this will enable your app to accomodate right-to-left locales automatically.  Only use `left` and `right` when you need something laid out on the left or right regardless of locale.

Answer (score 1):

CustomCell layoutSubviews cause infinite loop, you can set

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
   super.layoutSubviews()
   contentView.frame = frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 10, bottom: 15, right: 10))
}
```